# AX 2012 Security Development hide Menu Items

Tags: security, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to set up roles for some users on AX 2012 but I can't seem to hide some Menu Items.

Example: I give access to the Clients form.
Result: The **Sales** AND **Sales and Marketing** Menu Items are open and lead me to the Clients form.

What if I don't want that user seeing the Sales and Marketing Menu Item?

Moreover, some Menu Items are always accessible (Self Serve licence required to view them so anyone can see them) like the Work Items in the Home=> Common area. Well I want to hide those for a specific user.

I believe I have to do this by programming but I don't know where to start, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clients you refer to the CustTable 
and by Sales and sales and marketing you refer to Accounts Receivable and 'Sales and marketing'?

So am I correct and you want to allow access to the 'All customers' menu item but that would cause both of the modules to be visible and you only want one of them to be visible?

If so, I'm afraid it is indeed not inteded to work without having to code this. And secondly, I'm afraid that you will not be able to do so because Morphx handles this for us and we are not able to get into that part of Dynamcis Ax.

There might be a different solution or workaround. You could create a copy of the menu item and replace one of the menu items. That way, you would be able to put either of the menu items in different roles. ( but maybe you already had that in mind :) )

Comment: Yeah didn't think about "cheating" the system like you said in your workaround, guess i'll have to work with that. Sad to know I can't control such a trivial thing. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe for the Sales and Marketing menu item case, you could create a new Privilege in the AOT that gives permissions specifically for that menu item. Then, add that Privilege to a Duty (which should then be assigned to a Role).